# How to calculate the complexity of the HashMap search algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

How to calculate the complexity of the HashMap search algorithm? I'm googling result of this calculation - O(1), but I don't understand how they arrived at these findings.

Comment: Basic idea of hashing is to achieve O(1) complexity assuming hashing is collision free, so there is no need to calculate complexity for HashMap again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HashMap works on the hashing principle.It is the data structure that allow you to store and retrieve data in O(1) time provided we know the key.

In hashing, hash functions are used to link key and value in HashMap. Objects are stored by calling **put(key, value)** method of HashMap and retrieved by calling **get(key)** method. When we call put method, **hashcode()** method of the key object is called so that hash function of the map can find a bucket location to store value object, which is actually an index of the internal array, known as the table. HashMap internally stores mapping in the form of Map.Entry object which contains both key and value object. When you want to retrieve the object, you call the get() method and again pass the key object. This time again key object generate same hash code (it's mandatory for it to do so to retrieve the object and that's why HashMap keys are immutable e.g. String) and we end up at same bucket location. If there is only one object then it is returned and that's your value object which you have stored earlier. Things get little tricky when collisions occur.

**Collision** : Since the internal array of HashMap is of fixed size, and if you keep storing objects, at some point of time hash function will return same bucket location for two different keys, this is called collision in HashMap. In this case, a linked list is formed at that bucket location and a new entry is stored as next node.

If we try to retrieve an object from this linked list, we need an extra check to search correct value, this is done by **equals()** method. Since each node contains an entry, HashMap keeps comparing entry's key object with the passed key using equals() and when it return true, Map returns the corresponding value.

Since searching inlined list is O(n) operation, in worst case hash collision reduce a map to linked list. This issue is recently addressed in Java 8 by replacing **linked list** to the **tree** to search in O(logN) time.

By the way, you can easily verify how HashMap works by looking at the code of HashMap.java in your Eclipse IDE if you are keenly interested in the code, otherwise the logic is explained above.

**Information On Buckets :**  An instance of HashMap has two parameters that affect its performance: initial capacity and load factor. The capacity is the number of buckets in the hash table, and the initial capacity is simply the capacity at the time the hash table is created. The load factor is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its capacity is automatically increased. When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current capacity, the hash table is rehashed (that is, internal data structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has approximately twice the number of buckets.

Comment: how many buckets do we have regarding to our keys?

Comment: I have edited my answer, you will find your answer at the end. Thanks. ! @mlevytskiy

Comment: What happens when we have a `null` key in HashMap?